# How to make an Entry have lines?

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am trying to figure out how to make an Entry have multiple lines just like a Label. I would like to make it so that the entry is not scrollable horizontally because of the fact that it will have lines.
[image]

I am building the app on android so this is the most accurate picture I can provide. I would like my entry to be like the right one, adjusting to the multitude of the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entries always have a single line. You're looking for [Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor):

```xml
<Editor HeightRequest="250" />
```

You can also auto-size it to the text:

```xml
<Editor AutoSize="TextChanges" />
```

In the latter case, you must not set the `HeightRequest` property, though.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the "Editor", it's exactly what I was looking for.